# Connect Mini-PC to Laptop

Tags: remote-desktop, laptop-display

I got a mini pc. In fact, [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07CJ95LW9). I need a way to set it up, but I'm not sure how because, I don't have a monitor. The only thing I have is my MacBook Pro.

My question is, out-of-the-box, is there a way for me to connect the mini pc to my MacBook Pro to initially set it up? Or, is there a way for me to remote into the Mini PC to intitially set it up?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Short answer, No.

Comment: You need a monitor, keyboard, and probably also a mouse.  There are no alternatives at this point with a new PC.